# Regex for finding words containing more then 3 'a' characters

Tags: regex

I need to write a regex that will find all words with 3 or more 'a' letters. Suppose that each word is on a new line.
Example of correct words:

```
Anagram
Assassination
Abaca
```

I end up with something like this:

```js
^([^aA]*a[^aA]*a[^aA]*a)$
```

But it will not work correctly if there will be more than 3 'a' letters or if word starts with 'a'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would keep it simple and just use:

```regex
\b\w*[Aa]\w*[Aa]\w*[Aa]\w*\b
```

### Demo

This regex pattern matches any word containing three lower/upper a/A characters in it, appearing anywhere in the word.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I tried:

```
^(?i)(?:[b-z]*a){3}[a-z]*$
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/OZnpz7/1)

- `^` - Start line anchor.
- `(?i)` - Match rest case-insensitive.
- `(?:[b-z]*a){3}` - A non-capture group where you would match 0+ characters ranging from b-z upto a literal "a". Repeated three times.
- `[a-z]*` - Match any possible remainder.
- `$`- End line anchor.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the anchors, you can add matching `.*` at the end, and add `\n` to the negated character class to prevent crossing newlines.

```
^[^aA\n]*[aA][^aA\n]*[aA][^aA\n]*[aA].*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8li1zp/1)

Or a bit shorter

```
^(?:[^aA\n]*[aA]){3}.*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GlyHfq/1)